# jquery get html of child input element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the html as a variable of the first input in an input group when an "addInput" link is clicked:

```js
$(".addInput").click(function() {
  var input = $(this).closest(".input-group").children().first().html();
  alert(input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="Format: 555-555-5555" name="phone" value="419-555-1212" disabled required>
    <div class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="addInput"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></div>
    <div class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="deleteInput"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like an XY question. Needing to get the HTML of an element at runtime is a little odd. From the context of the code, are you trying to add another input when the `.addInput` is clicked? If so, use `clone()`, then `append()`

Comment: [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: yes that is my end goal, to add another input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needing to get the HTML of an element at runtime is a little odd. From the context of the code, it seems as though you're trying to add another input when the `.addInput` is clicked? If so, use `clone()`, then you can `insertAfter()` to place the new input directly after the original:

```js
$(".addInput").click(function() {
  var original = $(this).closest(".input-group").find('input:first');
  original.clone().insertAfter(original);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control phone" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="Format: 555-555-5555" name="phone" value="419-555-1212" disabled required>
    <div class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="addInput"><span class="fa fa-plus">+</span></a></div>
    <div class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="deleteInput"><span class="fa fa-minus">-</span></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Two things to note, though. Firstly I removed the `id="phone"` on the element to be cloned. If you don't do this you'll end up with multiple elements charing an `id` which is invalid. You can use a `class` instead.

Secondly, that if you want to clear the value of the clone, use `val('')`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a id to the input element and get the value of that

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input id="your-id-here" type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="Format: 555-555-5555" name="phone" value="419-555-1212" disabled required>
    <div class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="addInput"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></div>
    <div class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="deleteInput"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></a></div>
</div>
```

and in **JS**

```
//add input fields
$(".addInput").click(function() {
  var input = $('your-id-here').val();
  alert(input);
});
```

Comment: From OP: `yes that is my end goal, to add another input`